# jQuery this and toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi friends I try learning jquery but I get some issues,
red label below picture- when i clicked it toggle is opening but when I clicked second one again first div is opening
[image: red label below picture- when i clicked it toggle is opening but when I clicked second one again first div is opening]

my html

```
<ul class="otel-filtre-fiyat-tab">
                    <li class="otel-views"><a href="#"><img src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png" alt="" class="memnuniyet-durum" />
                        <strong>88/100</strong>
                        <span class="otel-goruntuleme">274 Görüntüleme</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="otel-prices"><a href="#">
                        <strong>Tüm Fiyatlar</strong>
                        <span class="otel-goruntuleme">Size Özel en uygun fiyatlar</span>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
                </div><!--otel filtre ozellikler-->
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--otel tek liste-->

            <div class="otel-filtre-tab">
                <div class="otel-tab-icerik otel-full-detay">
                    <div class="otel-degerlendirme">
                        <div class="degerlendirme-baslik">Değerlendirme</div>
                        <div class="otel-tab-detay">
                        <div class="degerlendirme-not">
                            <div class="c100 p85 green">
                              <span>85%</span>
                              <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div><!--dairesel genel değerlendirme-->


                        </div><!-- degerlendirme not -->

                        <div class="degerlendirme-yorum">
                            <div class="yorum-bar">
                                <div class="yorum-bilgi">
                                    <p>
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-kisi">Hakan2020</span> 
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-konum">Denizli,Türkiye</span>
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-tarih">26 Eylül 2015</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div><!-- yorum bilgi -->
                                <div class="otel-yorum-profil">
                                    <img src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/profile.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="yorum-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">“Özellikle, yeme içme kalitesi arayanlar için...”</a></h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque provident accusantium sint tempore! Fugiat debitis maxime eos? <a href="#">Devamını oku</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- yorum bar-->
                            <div class="yorum-bar">
                                <div class="yorum-bilgi">
                                    <p>
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-kisi">Hakan2020</span> 
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-konum">Denizsiz,Türkiye</span>
                                    <span class="otel-yorum-tarih">26 Eylül 2015</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div><!-- yorum bilgi -->
                                <div class="otel-yorum-profil">
                                    <img src="http://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/profile.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="yorum-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">“Özellikle, yeme içme kalitesi arayanlar için...”</a></h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque provident accusantium sint tempore! Fugiat debitis maxime eos? <a href="#">Devamını oku</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- yorum bar-->

                        </div><!-- degerlendirme yorum -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div><!-- otel degerlendirme-->

                        <h3>Genel Değerlendirme</h3>


                        <div class="otel-genel-degerlendirme">
                            <div class="tum-degerlendirmeler">
                                <a href="#" class="tab-zero-link">Tüm Değerlendirmeler</a>
                                <h4>Tüm İzlenimler</h4>
                                <h4 class="degerlendirme">%77 Çok İyi <span>2524 yoruma göre</span></h4>
                            </div><!--tum degerlendirmeler-->
                            <div class="diger-degerlendirmeler">
                                <ul class="tab-degerlendirme">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="ciftler-bg">%35 Çiftler</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="aile-bg">%35 Aile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="is-seyahati-bg">%35 İş Seyahati</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="yalniz-gezginler-bg">%35 Yalnız Gezginler</a></li>
                                </ul><!--tab menuler-->
                            <div class="tab-degerlendirme-icerik">
                                <div class="tab-filtre-icerik" id="ciftler">
                                    <div class="demo-show2">
                                      <h3>KAHVALTI <span class="accord-progress"></span><span class="mmn-oran">59%</span><span class="span-list">“Kahvaltı İyi”</span><span class="accord-chevron"></span></h3>
                                      <div>Deneme 1 'in içeriği</div>
                                      <h3>KAHVALTI <span class="accord-progress"></span><span class="mmn-oran">59%</span><span class="span-list">“Kahvaltı İyi”</span><span class="accord-chevron"></span></h3>
                                      <div>Deneme 2 'in içeriği</div>
                                      <h3>KAHVALTI <span class="accord-progress"></span><span class="mmn-oran">59%</span><span class="span-list">“Kahvaltı İyi”</span><span class="accord-chevron"></span></h3>
                                      <div>Deneme 3 'in içeriği</div>
                                    </div>
                                <!--<div id="progressbar-durum">
                                  <div></div>
                                </div>-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-filtre-icerik" id="aile">aile..
                                    %35

                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-filtre-icerik" id="is-seyahati">iş seyahati..</div>
                                <div class="tab-filtre-icerik" id="yalniz-gezginler-bg">yalnız gezginler..</div>
                            </div><!-- tab icerik kismi-->
                            </div><!--diger degerlendirmeler-->
                        </div><!-- otel genel değerlendirme-->


                </div><!-- tab icerik-->
                <div class="otel-tab-icerik otel-fiyat-detay-icerik">otel içerik 2..</div><!-- tab icerik -->
            </div><!-- otel filtre tab -->
```

toggle.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".otel-views a").on("click",function(){
        $(".otel-full-detay:first").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

what was my mistake ?

and codepen link:

```
http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/rxdpLp
```

Comment: Well your selector specifically says `:first` so I don't know why you expected it not to always open the first element.

Comment: Could you paste your HTML so we can help you to understand how it works ?

Comment: @Juhana I want when I cliked first li a first toggle has to open but when I clicked second li a second toggle has to be open (sorry about my english)

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to do but `:first` is obviously never going to toggle the second div.

Comment: it's added thanks @LolWalid

Comment: and any way to do ? how can I achivement :/ @Juhana

Comment: I have to div and I have a .otel-views a link inside div.I clicked to links but every div has to be open it's toggle (my english so bad rather than my jquery...)

Comment: You have to remove the :first, take look at the jquery documentation. I can't help right now, but i thing something like `$(this).parent('.otel-tekli-listeleme').find('.otel-full-detay').slideToggle();` will work (adjut it to make it work)

Comment: I tried didn't work but Do not toggle all .otel-full-detay this code ?

Comment: codes return 'undefined'

Comment: It's not the exact code, you have to adjust it. The process is easy -> Get the parent of your `.otel-views a` then find the `otel-full-detay` you want to toogle. I can't write you the right code because your DOM is pretty big but you can do it yourself

Comment: no I know and I did it but nevertheless didn't work but I understand clearly thanks

Comment: and I did it.$(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-full-detay").slideToggle(); using parents instead parent thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use other selector to reach your needed element. First you need to climb up in dom tree with `.parent()` or similar selector and then go down to your element in dom tree with `.children()` or `.find()` or other similar selector.

This is your working example:

```
$(".otel-views a").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.otel-tekli-listeleme').find('.otel-full-detay').slideToggle();
      return false;
});
```

Here's fixed [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjrYaZ)

Comment: and I did this function for another li a which has .otel-prices classes I wonder that How to close toggled div when another div is triggered ?